# The dual space of $C[0,1]$

Tags: banach-spaces

Since $C[0,1]^{*}$ is an abstract $L$-space, $C[0,1]^{*}$ is order isometric to $L_{1}(\mu)$ for some measure $\mu$.

My question is: the measure $\mu$ can be choosen to be a finite positive measure?

Thank you!

Comment: No, this measure is not sigma-finite.  See if you can prove it!

Comment: Thanks, Gerald! Is the dual of $C[0,1]$ the space of Radon measures on $[0,1]$?

Comment: Is the dual of C[0,1] the space of Radon measures on [0,1]?  Yes, certainly; this is the famous Riesz representation theorem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In an $L^1(\mu)$ space, we can tell when two elements are disjoint (that is, have disjoint support):
$f_1, f_2$ are disjoint if and only if $\|f_1\pm f_2\| = \|f_1\|+\|f_2\|$.

I claim that if $L_1(\mu)$ is isometric to $C[0,1]^*$, then $\mu$ is not sigma-finite.  To do this, it suffices to exhibit an uncountable pairwise disjoint family in $C[0,1]^*$.  Here is the easiest one:
$$
\varepsilon_t(f) := f(t)
$$
defines the "point evaluations" $\varepsilon_t$, one for each $t \in [0,1]$.  So now all we have to do is observe that
$$
\|\varepsilon_t \pm \varepsilon_s\| = \|\varepsilon_t\| + \|\varepsilon_s\|,
\qquad s \ne t $$
where $\|\cdot\|$ is the dual space norm.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar Thanks, Gerald. The proof is nice and elementary.